# Initiate single instance from a constructor and use it as static method in another class

Tags: javascript, class, oop

I have a class of utilities that I use all over my app
it contains a method to format numbers

```
class Utils {
    static numberFormater () {
        return new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US')
    }
}
```

the problem is whenever I call it it will return new numberFormat instance (which affects the performance of the code)

I want to make one instance and use it whenever I call this method

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not simply create an instance of the number formatter directly? Doesn't even need to be a static property:

```js
class Util {
  constructor () {
    this.numberFormatter = new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US');
  }
}

const util = new Util;

const formatter1 = util.numberFormatter;
const formatter2 = util.numberFormatter;

console.log(formatter1 === formatter2);
```

Comment: please fix the variable name (formatter) to (formatter1)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a [constructor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes#Class_declarations) which initializes the `numberFormater`.

```js
class Util {
  constructor(locale) {
    this.numberFormater = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale);
  }
  static numberFormater() {
    return this.numberFormatter;
  }
}

var a = new Util('en-US');
console.log(a.numberFormater.format);
```

Comment: I prefer the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51200972/need-to-initiate-single-instance-from-a-constructor-and-use-it-as-static-method/51201084#answer-51201081), but I'll leave this one up.

Comment: class Util {
  constructor(locale) {
    this.numberFormater = new Intl.NumberFormat(locale);
  }
  static numberFormater() {
    return this.numberFormatter;
  }
}

var a = new Util('en-US');

let b = a.numberFormater;
let c = a.numberFormater;

console.log(a === b);

this returns false I think it still create new instance for each call

Comment: `console.log(a === b);`, did you mean `console.log(b === c);`? `a` in that instance is the class `Util`, `b` and `c` would be the actual number formatter (which returns true for me)

Comment: oh sorry my bad

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make one instance and use it every time you can use a [Singleton pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

> The singleton design pattern solves problems like:
>
> 1. How can it be ensured that a class has only one instance?
> 2. How can the sole instance of a class be accessed easily?
> 3. How can a class control its instantiation?
> 4. How can the number of instances of a class be restricted?

More information on the pattern and javascript you can read:

1. [Singleton pattern in ES6](https://medium.com/@dmnsgn/singleton-pattern-in-es6-d2d021d150ae)
2. [Singleton pattern with example](http://jargon.js.org/_glossary/SINGLETON_PATTERN.md)
3. [JavaScript Design Patterns: Singleton](http://robdodson.me/javascript-design-patterns-singleton/)